# How can I download MP4 file from https link with redirect in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, download, mp4

Again I have a problem that I cannot solve, I am learning Node.js and there are many things that I do not know. The thing is the following, I have the following file called downloader.js

```
const https = require ('https')
const fs = require ('fs')
const path = require ('path')

function downloader (url, callback) {

    const filename = path.basename (url)

    const req = https.get (url, (res) => {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream (`$ {filename} .mp4`)
        res.pipe (file)

        file.on ("error", (error) => {
            console.log (`There was an error writing the file. Details: $ {error}`)
        })

        file.on ("close", () => {
            callback (filename)
        })

        file.on ('finish', () => {
            file.close ()
            console.log ("Completely downloaded.")
        })
    })

    req.on ("error", (error) => {
        console.log (`Error downloading file. Details: $ {error}`)
    })
}

module.exports = {
    downloader
}
```

And I have a video, which I get the download url from a call to the Zoom api, with the following link: https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/download/06L34fQudvvSaAGYJ6Chk6RC0fuV-ebwyu9Ar_Ihrm4WRmD3xbpPAjnYfIFInOBz1PBPPAjnYPhoJlf4p3xbpPAjnYFIFIXMD3xbpPAjnYFIFIXMD3xbpPAjnYphoJlf4

When calling the downloader function, all good, I download the file in mp4 format but, the problem is that it is not the full 700MB video in mp4 format, but it is an html document in mp4 format.

[Here you can see what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dte5T.png)

I do not understand why the file does not download correctly. When I do it with any other type of file such as a jpeg image, it downloads it without problems, but with the mp4 format I can't get the file to download. What do you think is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the link you posted points to an Error page saying the recording does not exist, I was unable to confirm this solution works.

However, assuming it functions similar to other recording links, when navigating to the location in a web browser, you are automatically redirected to a new uri to automatically start the download.

Assuming this is the case, what you are actually looking for is how to follow redirects on an external API request.

I would recommend the npm [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package, since it will automatically follow redirects.

You can then do something like:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function downloader(url, callback) {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const filename = path.basename(url);
                const file = fs.createWriteStream(`${filename}.mp4`);
                response.data.pipe(file);

                file.on("error", (error) => {
                    return reject(`There was an error writing the file. Details: $ {error}`);
                });

                file.on('finish', () => {
                    file.close();
                });

                file.on('close', () => {
                    return resolve(filename);
                });
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function (filename) {
            callback(filename);
        })
}

module.exports = {
    downloader
};
```

You could also directly return the axios promise and make your downloader function return a Promise instead of a function that takes a callback.

You could also try the [follow-redirects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects) package if you were looking to keep the `https` variable.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that the link is not available, as it has been manually deleted. I'll try this axios package and tell you how it went. Otherwise I will leave you a new link so you can try and help me solve this problem. Clearly the problem is that it is a redirect link.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for this. Now it is clearer to me and it is something new that I have learned. The follow-redirect package is a dependency of Axios, which, I already knew but had never worked with. Now I can have the file download by following the redirect the package. The code you sent me works perfect.